# SELECT Statement with substr in WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here sample table with three fields.

```
TableA

    FieldA        FieldB        FieldC
    ======================================
    123XYZ456     XYZ           John
    124NNN333     NNN           Jenny
    232XPT124     XPT           Jade
    456XXX345     XXX           James
```

`FieldA` has a fixedlength of 9. I didn't design this table and some applications are already using it.

I want to select `FieldB` and `FieldC` with conditions against `FieldA`.

Using this sql statement:

```
SELECT FieldB, 
       FieldC
FROM   TableA
WHERE  FieldA LIKE Concat(@paramA, '%', @paramB)
```

I cannot achieve my desired result. When I try to search with paramA value of `12` and paramB value of `''`, I get the `2` results:

```
    FieldA        FieldB        FieldC
    ======================================
    123XXX456     XXX           John
    124XXX333     XXX           Jenny
```

because obviously it matches with `12%` and that is not what I want. I want that the params should match the correct index of the string.

If I search for `paramA = '12'` and `paramB = ''` then it should have no result. To get the fields (`FieldB`, `FieldC`), I need the correct values of `paramA = '123'` and `paramB = '456'` so it will return `XYZ` and `John`. If I want to return `James` then i have to give `paramA = '456'` and `paramB = '345'`

How could I correctly build a SQL Statement for this? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: ur basically concerned abt first 3 and last 3 characters right?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right):

```
SELECT FieldB, FieldC
FROM   TableA
WHERE  LEFT(FieldA,3) = @paramA 
       AND RIGHT(FieldA,3) = @paramB;
```

Comment: thank you Adam. I'll be back in 3 minutes to accept the answer. :)

Comment: +1 for a working solution, but the remaining question is then *why* doesn't dynamic LIKE work?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT Field2,Field3
FROM TABLE
WHERE SUBSTR(Field1,1,3)='123' AND SUBSTR(Field1,7,3)='456'
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made it clear why you're even allowing paramB to be blank in your input validation but to get the exact behaviour you have described you could just check for that case, ie:

```
WHERE  @paramA!='' AND @paramB!='' AND FieldA LIKE Concat(@paramA, '%', @paramB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so: e.g classification table: Homes in America, Lands in America etc..

```
mysql_query("select classification from properties where LEFT(classification, 5) = 'Homes'");
```

Result: Homes